# Good Delphi Prism online resources

Tags: delphi, delphi-prism, oxygene

A Google search on "delphi prism", "delphi prism  resources" or "delphi prism code snippets" reveal almost no good sites at all are there any  good programming site(s) with some good amount of code snippets and tutorials on Delphi Prism?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@omair, you have you have basically five ways to obtain information about Delphi Prism

1) The official Info

- [Prism Wiki](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Main_Page)
- [Developing for Mono with Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero-info.com/whitepaper/Delphi_Prism_2010_and_Mono_WP_Brian_Long.pdf)

2) Using the Blogs

- [Introduction to Language Integrated Query with Delphi Prism: Part 1](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2009/06/introduction-to-language-integrated.html)
- [Introduction to Language Integrated Query with Delphi Prism, Part 2](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2009/07/introduction-to-language-integrated.html)
- [Using LINQ to Objetcs in Delphi Prism](http://www.andreanolanusse.com/blogen/using-linq-to-objetcs-in-delphi-prism/)
- [Introduction to Delphi Prism (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/net-languages/delphiPrismDemo.aspx)
- [Delphi Prism and the Cirrus Framework](http://jamiei.com/blog/2009/06/delphi-prism-cirrus-framework/)  (@jamiei blog)
- [Dynamically compiling code with Delphi Prism](http://jamiei.com/blog/2009/09/dynamically-compiling-code-with-delphi-prism/) (@jamiei blog)
- [Dynamically generating code with Delphi Prism](http://jamiei.com/blog/2009/10/dynamically-generating-code-with-delphi-prism/) (@jamiei blog)
- [Delphi Prism and the Microsoft Rx Framework](http://jamiei.com/blog/2010/03/delphi-prism-and-the-microsoft-rx-framework/) (@jamiei blog)

3) as @jamiei suggest Translate the C# or VB .Net Code to Delphi Prism is not difficult, you can use the [C# to Oxygene](http://code.remobjects.com/p/csharptoxy/) Tool  or you can do it manually.

4) the books

- [Delphi Prism Development Essentials Dr. Bob](http://www.bobswart.nl/weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:4065)
- [Delphi Prism Manual de referecnia (spanish)](http://www.gopac.com.mx/v3/gopache/embarcadero/LibroDelphiPrism.asp)
- [Delphi for .NET Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672324431) (this book is about delphi .Net but is very useful)
- [.NET 2.0 for Delphi Programmers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/NET-2-0-Delphi-Programmers-Shemitz/dp/1590593863) (very nice book, cover intermediate and advanced topics about .Net under a Delphi Programmer Perspective)

5) Ask in StackOverflow

Comment: Good round up of resources RRUZ. Although a few of those books will be slightly confusing to beginners because of the references to the now depreciated Delphi.NET?

Comment: I have published a PDF courseware manual on Delphi Prism (covering Delphi Prism 2010 at this time, but it's planned to get updated to Delphi Prism XE after which I will also publish it as paperback on Lulu.com). See http://www.eBob42.com/courseware for details (note: if you purchase the Delphi Prixm Development Essentials PDF courseware manual you also get the Delphi XE Development Essentials PDF as a free bonus - plus all update of both courseware manuals). I have also published a number of Delphi Prism articles at http://www.drbob42.com/examines and for CodeRage.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed, along with the [Prism Documentation Wiki](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Main_Page) it's worth noting that the best resources for .NET code are nearly all composed of C# code snippet sites.

The RemObjects team have built a [C# to Oxygene](http://code.remobjects.com/p/csharptoxy/) tool and have even [integrated it into the IDE](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2010/01/20/p818) so you can copy C# code from sites such as [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com) and paste it directly as Delphi Prism code into the IDE.

Comment: @jamei the C# to Oxygene tool integrated into the Delphi Prism IDE, will be available in the next official release of Delphi Prism.

Comment: @RRUZ I think it made it into the Delphi Prism 2010 February Release. If you bought RAD Studio 2010 with SA then I think you get the interim releases as included upgrades so 2010 customers may already have it.

Comment: @Jamei, check the footer note of the link http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2010/01/20/p818 `the “February” release will ship a bit later than February, this year, as we want to align it with the public release of Visual Studio 2010, which has been announced for April. Internally, we still refer to it as the “February Release”.`

Comment: @RRUZ I shall consider myself corrected, my advice is to get yourself onto the Beta pronto then.

Comment: does C# to Oxygene tool converts c# to delphi 100% ?

Comment: Yes, It converts to Delphi Prism. I've found it to be pretty effective but there are occasional problems so YMMV.

Comment: @Omair The problems will arise more with language features.  But most code you find inline should convert fine.

Answer (score 1):

Best place I find is http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Main_Page

There's also the various CodeGear and RemObjects newsgroups.

Comment: Moved to http://wiki.oxygenelanguage.com/en/Main_Page, FTR, in case the fredirect will stop working at some stage in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Prism was just a rebranding of the Oxygene compiler. If you search for Oxygene then you are more likely to find resources.